# Python: Why doesn't my scrollbar show up using Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Here is a snipet of my code:

```
dialog_canvas = Canvas(dialog_frame, scrollregion = (0, 0, 450, 265), bg = 'white')
dialog_canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH, side = LEFT)
yscroll = ttk.Scrollbar(root, orient = VERTICAL, command = dialog_canvas.yview)
dialog_canvas.config(yscrollcommand = yscroll.set)
yscroll.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = 'ns')
```

Comment: You've got the canvas in `dialog_frame` and the scrollbar in `root`. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)